# what's the benefit to inject a function instead of a dummy variable

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I was reading a unit test book, below is the code snippet:

```
const SUNDAY = 0; ... const SATURDAY = 6;

const verifyVoucher1 = (currentDay) => {
   if ([SATURDAY, SUNDAY].includes(currentDay)) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
};

const verifyVoucher2 = (getDayFn) => {
   const dayOfWeek = getDayFn();
   if ([SATURDAY, SUNDAY].includes(dayOfWeek)) {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
};
```

the author says `verifyVoucher2` is better than `verifyVoucher1` as `verifyVoucher1` make every caller ever needs to know about how to handle dates in some way. It feels a bit to “chatty”.

I don't really understand the point, for `verifyVoucher2`, how come every caller doesn't need to know about how to handle dates in some way? callers still has to make a fucntion by themselves and pass it to the `verifyVoucher2`, the only difference is now you wrap the day in a function.

so what's the benefit to pass `getDayFn` instead of `currentDay`?

Comment: First, seek explanation from the author directly, if possible. Second, the author probably talks about abstracting away implementation details, which means removing unrelated logic from a given context. In general, neither of the options is "better" or "worse"; for specific cases, one might be better. Third, every entity has a "contract", which other entities must respect if they want that entity to work properly. If the function is said to take an object input, other entities must call it with an object. If it takes a function input, other entities must call it with a function.

Comment: This will probably get closed due to opinion-based answers, but I'd encourage you to post this on a JS subreddit for deeper discussion, or try a cannot-be-named AI chat bot.

Comment: The question is not _opinion based_, IMO, because there probably is benefit to inject a function, objectively, as well as there is a benefit _not_ to do it. The questions asks what they are. -- But I also think this example doesn't illustrate one or the other. Probably the **original statement** and **some more context** should be added to the question.

Comment: You should also consider the simple case, that the author of the book is just wrong or chose a bad example, that does not match the point, that they try to convey.
Passing functions instead of configuration objects can have benefits in some cases, but in this case I cannot see any benefit.